# Difficulties sending worksheet through email via SendWorksheet button

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2016 worksheet with a "Send Worksheet" button purposed to email the worksheet to all the designated recipients. When I run the following code (most of which came from another program and tweaked), I receive the following errors:

> Runtime Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object.

at `Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

as well as

> Runtime Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

in the `With` block at `.To = "email address"`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSendWorksheet_Click()

Dim xFile As String
Dim xFormat As Long
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

'On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
ActiveSheet.Copy

Set Wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Select Case Wb.FileFormat
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook:
    xFile = ".xlsx"
    xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled:
    If Wb2.HasVBProject Then
    xFile = ".xlsm"
    xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Else
    xFile = ".xlsm"
    xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End If
End Select

FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
FileName = Wb.Name & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
Wb2.SaveAs FilePath & FileName & xFile, FileFormat:=xFormat

With OutlookMail
.To = "email address"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Worksheet Attached"
.Body = "Please see attached worksheet"
.cmdSendWorksheet.Enabled = True
.Attachments.Add Wb2.FullName
.Send
End With

Wb2.Close
Kill FilePath & FileName & xFile
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to run your macro with no errors until the statement `.cmdSendWorksheet.Enabled = True` (Error 438 - Object doesn't support this method). This makes sense because an Outlook email will not have a `cmdSendWorksheet` property - that's a method in your Excel application, not Outlook. As far as getting the error in creating the `Outlook.Application` object, I believe your installation of Outlook is not accessible by the Excel automation somehow. Double check how it's installed on your workstation.

Comment: Thank you! One question though - what would I do instead of .cmdSendWorksheet property? Also, thanks for the tip regarding the Outlook.Application object and Outlook..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code should do the job you need.  But you need to go in Tools / References and check the following reference :
Microsoft Scripting Runtime 
Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library

```
Private Sub cmdSendWorksheet_Click()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileExtensionName As String
Dim FileFullPath As String
Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

'On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
FileName = fso.GetBaseName(Wb.Path & "\" & Wb.Name) & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileExtensionName = fso.GetExtensionName(Wb.Path & "\" & Wb.Name)
FileFullPath = FilePath & FileName & "." & FileExtensionName
fso.CopyFile Wb.Path & "\" & Wb.Name, FileFullPath
'Sending the email
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutlookMail
    .To = "email address"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Worksheet Attached"
    .Body = "Please see attached worksheet"
    .Attachments.Add FileFullPath
    .Display
    '.Send          You can chose .Send or .Display, as you wish
End With
Kill FileFullPath
'Free the memory
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to fix a "compile error: user-defined type not defined" with this line: "Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application"?

Comment: Oh, and I did check Microsoft Scripting Runtime, but there was not the option for Microsoft 14.0 Object Outlook Library. Is it because I'm using Excel 2016?